# How is the global annotations limit on Google Custom Search Engines enforced?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

Google Custom Search Engines (CSEs) are said to have a limit of 5,000 annotations (sites/URLs) per *email account*. Therefore, a single email account can own multiple CSEs, but the 5,000 annotation limit will apply across all of them (summarised in this support thread: https://support.google.com/programmable-search/thread/20071397?hl=en)

My question: does anyone know the specifics of how these limits work? I own multiple CSEs with a combined total of well over 5,000 annotations, but I was at no point given an error or stopped from adding new annotations.

Will the CSEs only search 5,000 sites and just not return results from any others? How does it decide which 5,000 to look at?

Any clarifications very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/annotations#limits there is a limit of 5000 annotations per search engine, not per user.  In 2019 the limit was per user, but it was updated to be per search engine sometime in 2020.

You will get an error from the Programmable Search Engine control panel if you attempt to upload more than 5000 annotation per engine.

Comment: Very strange. I enquired yesterday in the Google help community, and a Google employee responded with something directly contradicting it (while doing nothing to answer my actual question!): https://support.google.com/programmable-search/thread/88909781?hl=en&authuser=1

They are still claiming that the 5,000 annotation limit applies across all of the account's search engines, rather than per search engine.

All very confusing.